# Geting a log of execution of current instructions when doing a 'docker run'

Tags: docker

I am a newbie to Docker and I am trying to see if I can get logs for the following instructions when they are getting executed.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV name John

ENTRYPOINT echo "Hello, $name"
```

My aim here is check how(the path etc.) the *shell* mode is working in executing the `ENV` here and also how the ENTRYPOINT is being executed.

I can imagine these kind of logs could be useful in debugging purposes, so probably I am missing something obvious. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfile instructions don’t do much; they record some state in fields in the built Docker image.  As @BrayanCaldera’s answer indicates, you’ll see these go by in the `docker build` output, but nothing runs during container build time.

If the ENTRYPOINT is a full-blown script then you can use usual script debugging techniques on it to see what happens when the container starts up.  For instance:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Print out every command as it executes
set -x
# Print out the current environment
env
# Run the actual command
exec "$@"
```

To tell the Docker image what to do by default when you `docker run` you should usually use the CMD directive.  If you need to do pre-launch setup then an ENTRYPOINT script that uses `exec "$@"` to run the CMD is a typical path.

Answer (score 0):

For see the logs on terminal you only need to execute this line:

```
docker build --rm -f dockerfile -t log:latest .
```

If you need to store these logs in a file you only need to execute this line:

```
docker build -t logs . > image.log
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question, bu you probably misread my question. I was asking about logs during 'docker run'